# aspx web form button couldn't return a right value when clicking in IE10

Tags: asp.net

My code is below.  When I run it in IE 10 and click button, `Page.Request.Form["button"]` returns the `innerText` of the button, "Add to Cart" instead of Value of the button, serverControl. However, it works in Google Chrome.  How to solve the issue?

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WorkWithControls
{
    public class ButtonCounterServerControl: WebControl
    {
        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            //base.RenderContents(writer);

            int countVal = (int) (Page.Session["server_control_counter"] ?? 0);

            if (Page.IsPostBack  && Page.Request.Form["button"] == "serverControl")
            {
                Page.Session["server_control_counter"] = ++countVal;
                int i = countVal;
            }

            output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
            output.Write("Server Control Button Process:");
            output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
            output.Write(countVal);
            output.RenderEndTag();
            output.RenderEndTag();

            output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, "button");
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, "serverControl");
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "submit");
            output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Button);
            output.Write("Add to Cart");
            output.RenderEndTag();
            output.RenderEndTag();    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing it from submit to button.  I have noticed some differences with IE between submit types button tags and button input types.  If that doesn't work you could always embed the information into another attribute that is working correctly then spit that data..  At least you would know that it would work then.  i.e   name = "button-serverControl"

Would help to also see rendered output.

Comment: If I use another attribute, how could I get it the value?  Page.Request.Form["button"] just returns innerText.  Thanks.